# array values confusion

Tags: c#, arrays

While working on a basic coding challenge I have come across a confusing situation that i am unable to fathom the cause of (I am new to programming)

whilst attempting to split a number into its individual digits, my int array contains the value 13 but returns the value 49??

there is probably an obvious reason for this and if so i apologize.

I have found an alternate way to split my numerical string into individual digits but would still like to know what i was doing wrong

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AddTheDigits
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt")) 
            {
                    //int total = 0;
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    //Console.WriteLine(line); //testing

                    char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray(0,1);

                    int[] intArray = new int[charArray.Length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        intArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(charArray[i]);
                        Console.Write(intArray[i]);
                    }
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the input? 13 and 49 don't mean anything if we don't know where they could come from.

Comment: What is the purpose of `ToCharArray(0, 1)`? You are only converting the first digit of every line to an integer and you do not need an array to do that.

Comment: Check the difference between `Convert.ToInt32` and `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: [`Char` represents a Unicode character as a UTF-16 code unit.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx#Relationship); Don't be confused by—otherwise correct—answers mentioning ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably mixing up the ASCII code for the digits with the digits themselves. Try replacing

```
intArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(charArray[i]);
```

with

```
intArray[i] = charArray[i] - '0';
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

you're taking you `line` (Which probably contains '13'), and grabbing the first `char` in it (`line.ToCharArray(0,1);`). You then convert this char (which has the numerical value 49, equal to '1' in UTF-16) to an int (still equals 49) and you print it. That's it. the '3' is left out due to the `ToCharArray` only grabbing the first character.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is essentially:

```
"13".ToCharArray(0,1);
```

which will give you the same value as :

```
char c = '1';
```

which is 49, the ASCII code for '1'

Answer (score 0):

49 is ASCII code for 1.

Instead of using `Int32.Convert`, you should use `Int32.Parse`.